# How to instantiate variable to object in Swift?

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6.1

My current swift code

```
    var itemToEdit = ChecklistItem
```

(then I use this var on viewDidLoad method: )

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let item = itemToEdit {
        title = "Edit Item"
        textField.text = item.text
    }

}
```

Is getting error: "expected member name or constructor call after type name" on the first line.
I tried to use "()" after ChecklistItem object and to write ".self" after object - then comes 2 error with this "if let item = itemToEdit" and this "textField.text = item.text" lines.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If "CheckListItem" is Type name, you must call initializer to create a instance.

```
var obj = CheckListItem() // Initializer with no arguments.
```

And Swift has two variable types, Normal type and Optional type that can be nil.

```
var optionalValue: Int? = nil //This is Optional type. (Add '?' to end of Type name)
var normalValue: Int = nil    //Error. Normal Int can not be nil.
```

Because "if let item = itemToEdit {" checks whether item is nil or not, itemToEdit must be optional type.

```
var itemToEdit: CheckListItem? = CheckListItem() //Declare as Optional type.
```

Comment: I am happy to be of help:)